# symfony2, call a service from Ajax client side

Tags: ajax, symfony, service

I've created a symfony2 service, that I would like to call from a client side Ajax(jQuery) and return the result of the query made by this service in the success function of the Ajax:

```
services:
  acme.services.exampleservice:
    class:  Acme\ExampleBundle\Services\ExampleService
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "GET",
     url: "?????????????",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result)
         { //do something with the result query }
});
```

Is this is possible ?, if so how could I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

No. But you can create a controller action, which calls your service and returns an appropriate response.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a route to a controller and have the controller do the work of finding your service and executing it with the correct params.

```
my_route:
    path: /ajax/my/service
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:MyController:myService }
```

Then in your controller:

```
<?php
class MyController 
{
    public function myServiceAction(Request $request) 
    {
        if ('POST' !== $request->getMethod() || !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            throw $this->createHttpNotFoundException();
        }

        $data = $this->get('acme.my_service.id')->myServiceMethod(/*...*/);

        return new JsonResponse(array($data/*...*/));
    }
}
```

Then on the client side, you can (in this example) do an ajax post to "/ajax/my/service" and get back the JsonResponse.